# Uniqueness validation for polymorphic model fails

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

So I have this really weird problem. Here is my model:

```
class Clip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :address, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:owner_type, :owner_id] }
  before_save { self.adress=adress.split("=").last }
  validates :owner, presence: true

end
```

and the test

```
test "invalid creations" do
  get new_clip_path
  assert_no_difference "Clip.count" do
    post clips_path, params: { clip: { address: "",
                                     description: "bum bum bum" } }
  end
  assert_template "clips/new"
  assert_match "blank", response.body
  assert_no_difference "Clip.count" do
    #clip allready in db, should refure
    post clips_path, params: { clip: { address: "fWNaR-rxAic",
                                    description: "bum bum bum" } }
  end
  assert_template "clips/new"
  assert_no_match "blank", response.body
  assert_match "Address has already been taken", response.body
end
```

The test is passing without a problem but I just realized by accident, that I can still create clips with the same address and owner, as often as I want to. This confuses me for two reasons: a) what is wrong with this line validates :address, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:owner_type, :owner_id] } and b) why does the test not fail?